# Glimpse SQL tab disabled

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

Glimpse SQL Tab is disabled. Has anyone faced this issue?

I checked the following:

- Glimpse ADO.NET enabled in the configuration.
- All connection strings have provider name set as System.Data.SqlClient
- No additional requests in the history tab.

Comment: how are your connections created? Make sure you use the `DBProviderFactories` as this is where Glimpse is hooking in

Comment: Thanks for the information, I am using normal sqlconnection objects and that is why I am not seeing SQL tab. After seeing your response, I searched the documentation and found this article [link]http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration

Comment: If possible try to use the `DBProviderFactories` approach, that way your code is not taking a direct reference on the Glimpse assemblies

Comment: Yes, thanks, I too considered same approach. There are lot of changes needed in the DAL :(